# basic haskell : Copying elements

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to recursively call a function that copies any type a specified amount of times
for example copy 3 'a' would give me ['a','a','a'] while copy 3 2 would give me [2,2,2]
This is what I have so far but I'm not sure if my typeline is correct as I think my code should run fine. Can anyone see what's wrong?

```
copy :: Int->a->[a]
copy x [] = []
copy y a = a:(copy (y-1) a)
```

edit: updated to this:

```
copy :: Int->a->[a]
copy 0 a = [] 
copy y a = [a]++(copy (y-1) a)
```

However this gives me "aaa" instead of [a,a,a]

Comment: what is the type of `copy x [] = []`? Does it match your signature? Are you having trouble interpreting your compiler's error messages?

Comment: In Haskell, strings are just lists of chars, that is, `"aaa"` is really `'a':'a':'a':[]`.

Comment: why not just use `replicate` ?

Comment: Also, in your updated version there is no need to use `++`; simple prepending with `:` as in the first version is fine.

Comment: @Claudiu is there anyway I can chose between the string or ['a','a','a']?

Comment: @John Both are the same thing.

Comment: @John: it's literally the same value. it's just a matter of how you display it. you can do `showStr s = concat ["[", concat $ intersperse "," $ map (\x -> "'" ++ [x] ++ "'") s, "]"]` if you want, `showStr "aaa"` gives you `"['a','a','a']"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a suggestion about how to implement your function in a more haskelly way. You are trying to implement standard `replicate` function and looking at the standard source code always help. Here is the code for replicate (after simplification)

```
replicate n x = take n (repeat x)
repeat x = xs where xs = x : xs
```

The source code is taken from the simplified src returned by lambdabot on haskell irc.

Comment: chances are, the OP doesn't know how to invoke lambdabot in such manner.