# haskell : How to report an error for my function

Tags: haskell

this is an expansion to my last question here: [basic haskell : Copying elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456756/basic-haskell-copying-elements)

however when an invalid input is added then I want it to print out an error message saying "negative value" or something similar. Is this possible in haskell?
working code:

```
copy :: Int->a->[a]
copy 0 _ = [] 
copy y a = [a]++(copy (y-1) a)
```

final line:

```
copy b c  = error "negative value"
```

Comment: Define "invalid input". (Also, the answer to the only actual question you asked is "yes".)

Comment: Calling `error` will abort your program with the error message, which is probably not what you want. You'll need to encode the error in the function's return type (ie: `Either String [a]` or `Maybe [a]`), and then check for a `Left err` or `Nothing` respectively in the function that calls `copy`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because partial functions make me sad, I'd suggest doing something more along the lines of

```
copy :: Int -> a -> Maybe [a]
copy 0 _ = Just []
copy n a | n < 0 = Nothing
         | otherwise = fmap (a:) (copy (n-1) a)
```

We've swapped out that `if` for a "guard"

```
foo bar | baz = quux
        | ...
```

is just

```
 foo bar = if baz then quux else ...
```

Note that I also changed your code a little,

```
 [a] ++ copy (y-1) a ====> fmap (a:)  (copy (y-1) a)
```

You can think of `(:)` as append.

```
 1 : [2, 3] ==> [1, 2, 3]
```

It's the preferred alternative to `[1] ++ [2, 3]`. Say it out loud as "cons", like "construct". We can write this with an operator section

```
(a:) ==> \x -> a : x
```

Next we use this wonky `fmap` function. Think of `fmap` like this

```
fmap f Nothing = Nothing
fmap f (Just x) = Just (f x)
```

So it unwraps a `Just` and applies a function before rewrapping the result. So our final code returns `Nothing` if our number is negative, otherwise, just the list.

Why aren't I recommending `error`? Well because `error` will blow up your whole program with pretty minimal information and it's a bad idea to try to catch it. Haskell doesn't even mandate that it's possible to do so, GHC just implements `error` in such a way that it's possible. In other words, you have little chance to recover.

This isn't a big deal for 10 lines of code, but I've spent upwards of 6 hours searching for the offending call to a function using `error`. It's much faster to debug and more idiomatic haskell.

Comment: +1 For the newbie-friendly step by step explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with guards

```
copy :: Int -> a -> [a]
copy n x
    | n < 0 = error "negative value"
    | n == 0 = []
    | otherwise = x : copy (n - 1) x
```

However, if this fails then it will likely crash your program.  A better way is to use the `Maybe` type:

```
copySafe :: Int -> a -> Maybe [a]
copySafe n x 
    | n < 0 = Nothing
    | otherwise = Just (copy n x)
```

Then you can use it as

```
main = do
    putStrLn "Enter a number:"
    nStr <- getLine
    let n = read nStr :: Int
        maybeXs = copySafe n n
    case maybeXs of
        Nothing -> putStrLn "You entered a negative number!"
        Just xs -> print xs
```

This style forces you to consider both cases of `copySafe`, either it can fail on a negative value or it can return a valid list.  It doesn't crash your program and the error handling is enforced by the type system.

Comment: I'd suggest defining `copy` in terms of `copySafe`, rather than the other way round.

Comment: @LambdaFairy I would too, but I wanted to stay away from `fmap` in this example.

Answer (score -6):

look at http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Error_vs._Exception

for example

```
copy b c = if c > b then error "negativ value"
```

Comment: Note that the `else` part of the `if` expression is not optional. Also, you should use `c :` rather than `[c] ++`.

Comment: I don't understand why this is the accepted answer. The example isn't valid syntax; and `b` and `c`, which are different types, cannot be compared with each other.

Comment: @LambdaFairy and 'negative' is spelled incorrectly for christ's sake